# Find String that starts and ends with a specific char

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find a string that **starts** and **ends** with a specific special character.

I tried the following regex but its not working:

```
(\#*\.|\&)[A-Za-z]+\.*#
```

I want to find any string that **starts with #*** and **ends with *#** but can't find the right [regex](https://regex101.com/r/fW9lZ2/4) for it.

Sample :

```
Hi this is test #*DCSN_RSN*# something found here #*DCSN_RerereSN.*#
```

I am trying to find the string `#*DCSN_RSN*#` in the above string and replace it with `<p>#*DCSN_RSN*#</p>`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "find a string"? For instance, do you mean within other text? Or do you mean you want to check *whether* a string (perhaps one of a list) starts and ends with a given pair of characters. Could you show specific inputs and what results you want from them?

Comment: Just use `/#\*.*?\*#/g` or `/#\*[\s\S]*?\*#/g`.

Comment: I am trying to find the specified string and update the string with opening and closing p tag.

Comment: Use `s.replace(/#\*.*?\*#/g, "<p>$&</p>")`

Comment: No need to escape `#`. Just `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
var sample = 'Hi this is test #*DCSN_RSN*# something found here #*DCSN_RerereSN.*#';

var replaced = sample.replace(/(#\*[\s\S]*?\*#)/g, '<p>$1</p>');
console.log(replaced);
```

To match any characters you can use `[\s\S]*`, then add `?` for `[\s\S]*?` to make it less-greedy. Your `*` characters also need to be escaped.